# MySQL custom datetime

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I am trying to display data associated with date. However in my case, I don't want the date to start at `00:00:00` and finishes at `23:59:59`. Rather I want it to start at `16:00:00` and finishes at `06:00:00` the next day. In other words I want to create a custom time for date.

In the same time I want to `GROUP_BY date`.

For instance I have these values in the database:

[image]

want it to give me:

```
date: 2013-09-08 count: 2
date: 2013-09-09 count: 1
```

I am not asking for code, but a way to think about it, or useful methods.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to take the existing date and subtract six hours to get the "effective" date.  You would do this for output purposes only.

Example:

```
select date(datecol - interval 6 hour) as MyDate, count(*)
from t
group by date(datecol - interval 6 hour);
```

You can use a `where` clause to remove the times between 6:00 and 16:00 (unless that is a typo).

Comment: Thank you! much simpler than I thought! Am using DATE_SUB and it's working!